# Remove Guest Login completely from mac

Tags: mac, big-sur, guest-account

Is there a way to completely remove the guest login option from macOS Big Sur? Meaning that it even does not appear anymore as an option in the settings or it is so corrupted that it does not work anymore.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, you should try to avoid ranting and passive-aggressive questions. Just stick to the fact. Will also be easier to read and understand. For this specific question, try to explain what problem you have regarding having the Guest account existing but disabled.

Comment: Hi @LudoMC, I am sorry I did not mean to be passive-aggressive. Apparently the Daemon edited my post, deleting the informal nice part at the end. I am trying to find a way to have the Guest account completely removed so it cannot be enabled via the settings interface. It would be more convenient for the use case on my computer. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, if you have Find My enabled, you cannot disable the guest. It is part of the security.

See [Apple KB - Change Users & Groups Guest User preferences on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-by/guide/mac-help/mh15600/mac)

Comment: What if you disable Find My?

Comment: Sure, then you can disable it - I'm not seeing the net gain there. Guest can't access anything of yours on the Mac, Find My is worth the price of the Mac if it's stolen.

Comment: The upside is to prevent myself to circumvent some restrictions I have set up for myself.. the guest account is pretty much a destruction of any website blocking tool on your admin account...

Comment: May I suggest … will-power. Anything you can do as an admin you can undo again just as easily.

Comment: Yeah that's indeed the only solution. Thanks for the support, I'll need to work on myself rather than against! :-)